# How to submit reactive form manually in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form of forms. So I need to submit the main form on the last child form submit. Is there a way to do it manually?

```
<form class="main-form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="sendData()">
  <form *ngIf="currentQuestion === 1" class="form" (submit)="nextQuestion()" formGroupName="nameQuestion"></form>
  <form *ngIf="currentQuestion === 3" class="form" (submit)="nextQuestion()" formGroupName="phoneQuestion"></form>
  <form *ngIf="currentQuestion === 4" class="form" (submit)="nextQuestion()" formGroupName="marketsQuestion"></form>
  <form *ngIf="currentQuestion === 5" class="form" (submit)="nextQuestion()" formGroupName="biographyQuestion"></form>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you don't need to use the `ngSubmit` if you don't want to. Remove that and add whatever logic you need to your `nextQuestion()` method.

```html
<form class="main-form" [formGroup]="form">
  <form *ngIf="currentQuestion === 1" class="form" (submit)="nextQuestion()" formGroupName="nameQuestion"></form>
  <form *ngIf="currentQuestion === 3" class="form" (submit)="nextQuestion()" formGroupName="phoneQuestion"></form>
  <form *ngIf="currentQuestion === 4" class="form" (submit)="nextQuestion()" formGroupName="marketsQuestion"></form>
  <form *ngIf="currentQuestion === 5" class="form" (submit)="nextQuestion()" formGroupName="biographyQuestion"></form>
</form>
```

In your component:

```js
nextQuestion(){

...

 if (currentQuestion === 5){
    this.form.values // Your form values, do what you want with them.
 }
}
```

Comment: No doubt it will work. But the nextQuestion() method single responsibilty is to increase currentQuestion. If I add a new question to the form, I will have to change the number in if(...) statement

Comment: Maybe I should get the number of subforms in the main form and compare currentQuestion with subforms.length

Comment: @jaba There you go, there are many options.